# Efficient way to fill up a 4d array from entries of a product of two matrices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

Title might be not as precise than I hoped, but here is the problem. Basically I'm filling a 4d numpy array from the entries of the product of two matrices. Right now the code is the following :

```
M = P.dot(U)
C_arr = np.zeros((b_size,b_size,N,N))
  for alpha in xrange(b_size):
      for beta in xrange(b_size):
          for i in xrange(N):
              for j in xrange(N):
                  C_arr[alpha,beta,i,j] = np.conjugate(M[i,alpha])*M[j,beta]
```

It turns out that this function is called quite ofen and appears to be very time-consumming. I'm just beginning with Python and I suspect that there could be a more efficient way to write this function by avoiding those loops, but haven't been able to figure it out by myself...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html):

```
C = np.einsum('ia,jb->abij', M.conj(), M)
```

Or, since there is no actual sum being computed (i.e. this is a form of an outer product), you can use numpy broadcasting with regular array multiplication after reshaping the input matrix `M` appropriately:

```
nrows, ncols = M.shape
C = M.T.reshape(1, ncols, 1, nrows) * M.T.conj().reshape(ncols, 1, nrows, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the terse code with `np.einsum` listed in the other solution, you can also use outer-product with [`np.outer`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html) like so -

```
np.outer(M.conj().ravel(),M.ravel()).reshape(N,b_size,N,b_size).transpose(1,3,0,2)
```

Runtime tests -

```
In [54]: # Create input and get shape parameters
    ...: M = np.random.rand(10,10)
    ...: N,b_size = M.shape
    ...: 

In [55]: %timeit np.einsum('ia,jb->abij', M.conj(), M)
10000 loops, best of 3: 26 µs per loop

In [56]: %timeit np.outer(M.conj().ravel(),M.ravel()).reshape(N,b_size,N,b_size).transpose(1,3,0,2)
10000 loops, best of 3: 55.6 µs per loop

In [57]: # Create input and get shape parameters
    ...: M = np.random.rand(40,40)
    ...: N,b_size = M.shape
    ...: 

In [58]: %timeit np.einsum('ia,jb->abij', M.conj(), M)
10 loops, best of 3: 31 ms per loop

In [59]: %timeit np.outer(M.conj().ravel(),M.ravel()).reshape(N,b_size,N,b_size).transpose(1,3,0,2)
10 loops, best of 3: 24.2 ms per loop

In [60]: # Create input and get shape parameters
    ...: M = np.random.rand(80,80)
    ...: N,b_size = M.shape
    ...: 

In [61]: %timeit np.einsum('ia,jb->abij', M.conj(), M)
1 loops, best of 3: 497 ms per loop

In [62]: %timeit np.outer(M.conj().ravel(),M.ravel()).reshape(N,b_size,N,b_size).transpose(1,3,0,2)
1 loops, best of 3: 399 ms per loop
```

Thus, depending on the shape of the input array, you can go either way.